# Counter Up v2 plugin in Angular (animated counter)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I'd like to use Animating Numbers Counting Up with Counter-Up Plugin ( [Counter Up v2](https://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/Animating-Numbers-Counting-Up-with-jQuery-Counter-Up-Plugin.html) ) with Angular *(Angular CLI: 11.2.2, Node: 14.16.0, OS: win32 x64)*, but I have problem making it work.

1. [npm install counterup2 --save] is installed
2. [import { counterUp } from 'counterup2';]  is imported in app.ts.module - with info: 'counterUp' is declared but its value is never read.
3. [declare module 'counterup2';] in new file 'counterup.t.ds' added
4. I see it in packages.json: "counterup2": "^1.0.4", and in package-lock.json
5. I should add code:

```
counterUp(document.querySelector('.counter') {
  duration: 1000,
  delay: 16
})
```

but I somehow do it wrong - I tried in different plases and have info, that ',' is expected in the place of {

Where exactly should be put this code to be able use it?

6. I tried to add in app.ts.module:

```
imports: [
     counterUp,
...
```

I'v got error: "src/app/app.component.html:1:1 - error NG8001: 'router-outlet' is not a known element" (Content of app.component.html is only: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`)

Comment: But you're using a jQuery plugin in an Angular project! With `document.querySelector` in the middle, which is not even jQuery, much less Angular. Of course it can't work. You need an Angular version of this plugin.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, but in description was: "Note that the Counter Up v2 has removed the jQuery dependency.", so I hoped that it will works with Angular

Comment: No, same thing. jQuery or Vanilla Javascript, things like `document.getElementById` or `.addEventListener("click")` have nothing to do in an Angular app because they don't integrate in Angular's life cycle. You can maybe manage to make them work, with hacks and workarounds like `setTimeout` and all, but it's dirty and will quickly lead to a dodgy and unmaintainable application.

Answer (score 1):

Your steps are wrong from *step 2*.

After installing the package(It's package, not plugin),

1. At *app.component.html* create an html element `<div class="counter">1,123,456 downloads</div>`
2. And at *app.component.ts.ts* import it like `import counterUp from 'counterup2'`
3. Now on it's `ngOnit` write the code

```
const el = document.querySelector( '.counter' )

// Start counting, do this on DOM ready or with Waypoints.
counterUp( el, {
    duration: 1000,
    delay: 16,
} )
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-so-66548954

Comment: Thx naveen. It seems to work, but without one feature. On  Counter Up v2 demo site, counting start when the counter goes to view during page scrolling. For example for code:
```<div style="padding-top:1500px" class="counter">1,123,456 downloads</div>
<div style="padding-top:50px" class="counter">1,123,456 downloads</div>
<div style="padding-top:50px" class="counter">1,123,456 downloads</div>
<div style="padding-top:50px" class="counter">1,123,456 downloads</div>```

Comment: 1. [npm i waypoints -S] Waypoints module added
2. and I realised that, the problem is with any next class="counter" elements. Only first one is working, for example:
```
<span class="counter">2,345,678 downloads</span>
<div class="counter">123,456</div>
<span style="padding-top:2000px" class="counter">81</span><span class="number"><sup>%</sup></span>
<div class="counter">1,123,456</div>
```

Comment: So, now I'm a bit closer, but your test app works for only first class="counter" elements. 
For example: ```<span class="counter">345,678 downloads</span> 
<div class="counter">123,456</div> 
<span style="padding-top:2000px" class="counter">81</span>
<span class="number"><sup>%</sup></span> 
<div class="counter">1,123,456</div>```
Is possiblilty to move all elements with class="counter"?

Answer (score 0):

I have already managed to 'multi-start' counters (code below) but in ***naveen*** testapp one feature didn't work: on Counter Up v2 demo site (https://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/Animating-Numbers-Counting-Up-with-jQuery-Counter-Up-Plugin.html), the counter starts only when the element is in the visible area (after scrolling the screen). I don't know how to do this in Angilar. I will be grateful for help.

```
<h3>Counter Demo</h3>
<span class="counter">2,345,678 downloads 1234</span>
<div class="counter2">123,456</div>
<span class="counter3">81</span><span class="number"><sup>%</sup></span>
<div style="padding-top:1500px" class="counter4">1,123,456</div>
```

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
 ngOnInit(): void {
    const el = document.querySelector('.counter');
    const el2 = document.querySelector('.counter2');
    const el3 = document.querySelector('.counter3');
    const el4 = document.querySelector('.counter4');    
    counterUp(el, {
        duration: 1000,
        delay: 16,
    });
    counterUp(el2, {
      duration: 1000,
      delay: 16,
    });
    counterUp(el3, {
      duration: 1000,
      delay: 16,
    });
    counterUp(el4, {
      duration: 1000,
      delay: 16,
    });
  }
}
```